# multiply matrix4x4 with vec4

Tags: opengl, mathematics, glsl, matrix, lwjgl

I'm developing a game and
I'd like to make model * pos4 calc (that's usual in glsl vertex shader) in cpu instead of doing it in gpu. I'm using LWJGL and for the math impl I use JOML. Anyone know how to multiply a vec4 with a matrix 4x4? It would be nice showing me the JOML code but also the way to mul the mat values with the vec4 values is fine!

Comment: Check the JOML documentation. There are plenty of variations of `Matrix4f.transform*()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrix-vector multiplication works the same as matrix-matrix multiplication, because a 4d vector is basically matrix with one of the dimensions equal to 1.

---

If we have a vector `v = (x; y; z; w)` and a matrix

```
    a b c d
M = e f g h
    i j k l
    m n o p
```

Then `M * v` is equal to

```
(x*a + y*b + z*c + w*d;
 x*e + y*f + z*g + w*h;
 x*i + y*j + z*k + w*l;
 x*m + y*n + z*o + w*p)
```

And `v * M` is equal to

```
(x*a + y*e + z*i + w*m; 
 x*b + y*f + z*j + w*n; 
 x*c + y*g + z*k + w*o; 
 x*d + y*h + z*l + w*p)
```

---

To do `M * v` in JOML, you need to use the matrix's `transformPosition()` method:

```
yourMatrix.transformPosition(yourVector);
```

Comment: Thank you Balint, but the calcule is not vector4 * matrix4x4, it's matrix4x4 * vector4. Is it the same? If not could you edit the question? I would be really pleased.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't been clear in the title.

Comment: @loyruta I messed it up a bit, those calculations are M * v. Also, M * v in row major is also v * M in column major

Comment: @Bálint I think you're using slightly incorrect terms. {row|column} major ordering has nothing to do with how computations are performed. It's just a way of storing 2D array in memory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/row-major-vs-column-major-vector "If you decide to write the vectors in column-major order instead ([3x1]), the [3x3] matrix needs to be on the left side of the multiplication and the vector or point on the right side"

Comment: @Bálint See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order The author of that tutorial seems to incorrectly understand these terms.

Comment: Also, `v * M equals either ... or ...` is not true. If you treat `v` as column vector, then `v * M` is not computable. When you do `v * M`, the `v` is always assumed to be row vector. When you do `M * v`, v is column vector. (Well, you just said that yourself.) | *"Because glsl uses column-major matrices, ..."* Nope, not true. OpenGL uses them indeed, but it's irrevelant. GLSL supports both `v * M` and `M * v`. In first case it assumes `v` to be row vector, in the second case - column vector. The formula depends *only* on choice of multplication order: `M * v` (usually) or `v * M`.

Comment: @Bálint Won't you mind if I edit your answer to correct things I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

**You should read these [nice tutorials](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/index.htm) about matrices and vectors.**

`matrix × vector` is a degenerate case of `matrix × matrix` multiplication.

(A vector can be considered a matrix with width or height equal to 1.)

---

Here is how `matrix × matrix` multiplication is performed:

Assume we have two matrices, `A` and `B`.

If `A` has size `m×n` and B has size `n×p`, then the resulting matrix `C` will have size `m×p`.

(We're using mathematical notation here. In `α×β` the first letter denotes height and the second letter denotes width.)

Notice how the same letter `n` denotes both the width of `A` and height of `B`. If they are different, you can't multiply such matrices.

Let's call resulting matrix `C(m×p)`.

Then, to get a single element `C[y][x]` of the resulting matrix, you must take y-th row from the `A` and x-th column from the `B`, multiply them component-wise and add together the results.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
const int m = ...;
const int n = ...;
const int p = ...;

float a[m][n] = {...};
float b[n][p] = {...};
float c[m][p];

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
        c[i][j] = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

---

For example, if

```
    / 1 2 5 \         / 0 5 \
A = | 3 5 4 |     B = | 3 9 |
    \ 0 7 9 /         \ 1 4 /
```

Then `C` will be 2 numbers wide and 3 numbers high.

Let's compute a single element:

```
C[2][1] = A[2][0] * B[0][1] +
          A[2][1] * B[1][1] +
          A[2][2] * B[2][1] = 

        =    0    *    5    +
             7    *    9    +
             9    *    4    =

        = 99
```

---

As I said, when you multiply a vector and a matrix together, the vector is treated as a matrix too. If you do `vector × matrix`, then `vector` is treated as a matrix of size `1×n`. If it's `matrix × vector`, then `vector` has size `n×1`.

It's not too hard to understand. If you orient your vector incorrectly (`1×n` instead of `nx1` or vice versa), then the width of `A` would no longer be equal to the height of `B`.

Resulting vector will always have the same orientation (row or column) as the original vector.

---

**P.S.** I'm not familiar with JOML, but if @Bálint is correct, then `yourMatrix.transformPosition(yourVector);` performs `matrix × vector`, which is what you need.

---

**P.P.S.** @Bálint 's claim that memory ordering of a matrix (row or column major) affects computations is not correct. The above formula always holds true.

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?